# How to emit Dbus signal in C

Tags: qt, dbus, qdbus

I am having a method and signal. From one process which is developed in Qt Creator 5.2.1, has 1 method and 1 signal.
The method is called using QDbusConnection and QDbusMessage.
The signal is connected with one slot.

A remote application which is to be developed in C should call the method remotely and should emit signal.

I need to know the sequence to remotely run the method and the sequence to emit signal.
Please help me the sequence in C program. No clear picture I found while surfing in internet.

Comment: Did u try this? http://www.matthew.ath.cx/misc/dbus

Comment: matthew.ath.cx is currently down. but you can find the files on github by name dbus-example.c under wware/stuff/dbus-example/. and the version is with some fixes too.